# Imagen no abre en ventana modal cuando es añadida con append() de jquery

Tags: java, jquery, imagen, modal, click

Urgente por favor.

Tengo el siguiente código javascript para abrir una imagen en una ventana modal. Este SI FUNCIONA para imagenes que estén agregadas normalamente así:

```
<div class="product-item " category="cremas">
   <img class="imagen" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiovannyJara/biopiante/gh-pages/images/1_1_Crema_Restauradora_Reafirmante_Arrugas.png" alt="" >
</div>;
```

EL PROBLEMA ES: cuando agrego este mismo código para imágenes con jquery append(), como lo muestro a continación, no FUNCIONA, es decir doy click en la imagen y no la abre la imagen en la ventana modal. Debo reiterar que la imagen si abre pero cuando es código estático o sea cuando no está agregado con la función append():

```
    var data2=`<div class="product-item " category="cremas">
             <img class="imagen" src="`+value.imagen+`" alt="" >
        </div>`;

$("#crema").append(data2);
```

Javascript para abrir imagen

```
      $('.imagen').click(function(){
          var imagen1=$(this).attr('src');
          var titleimagen=$(this).attr('title');
          if (imagen1==""){
            $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src','http://www.51allout.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image-not-found.gif');
            $('#mimodal').modal();
          }else{
              $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src',imagen1);
              $('.texto-imagen').text(titleimagen);
              $('#mimodal').modal();
        }
      });
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU ATENCIóN

Comment: Usa `on("click")`

Comment: @alanfcm LO PUSE ASí Y NO FUNIONA     $('.imagen').on( "click", function() {
  var imagen1=$(this).attr('src');
              var titleimagen=$(this).attr('title');
      
              if (imagen1==""){
      
                $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src','http://www.51allout.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image-not-found.gif');
                $('#mimodal').modal();
      
              }else{
                  $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src',imagen1);
                  $('.texto-imagen').text(titleimagen);
                  $('#mimodal').modal();
            }
});

Comment: Intenta `$('#crema').on( "click", '.imagen'', function() {`

Comment: Amigo @alanfcm MUCHAS GRACIAS ! funcionó correcto. Al hacer el click sobre cada imagen si la abre en el modal.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá lo correcto sea usar

```
$("#crema").html( data2 );
```

Comment: Hola qué tal , gracias por responder, ya lo puse así y No funciona.

Comment: Tienes razón. Es #cremas (en plural)

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto este código, donde tiene la funcionalidad que requieres.
Ojo, que cuando realizabas

```
$("#crema").append(data2);
```

Debes tener en cuenta que si hacías referencia al valor "category" del `div` debes ver que se llama `cremas` no `crema`. Aun así no puedes hacer una referencia en Jquery a ese atributo de la forma `$("#cremas")` ya que ese valor no es un identificador dentro del DOM.

```js
function agregar(){
  var imagen = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiovannyJara/biopiante/gh-pages/images/1_1_Crema_Restauradora_Reafirmante_Arrugas.png';
  var data2=`<div class="product-item " category="cremas">
             <img class="imagen" src="${imagen}" alt="" >
        </div>`;
  $("#contenedor").append(data2);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('click', '#agregar', function(){
    agregar();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.imagen', function(){
      var imagen1=$(this).attr('src');
      var titleimagen=$(this).attr('title');
      if (imagen1==""){
        $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src','http://www.51allout.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image-not-found.gif');
        $('#mimodal').modal();
      }else{
          $('.recibir-imagen').attr('src',imagen1);
          $('.texto-imagen').text(titleimagen);
          $('#mimodal').modal();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="agregar">Agregar imagen</button>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="product-item " category="cremas">
     <img class="imagen" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiovannyJara/biopiante/gh-pages/images/1_1_Crema_Restauradora_Reafirmante_Arrugas.png" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>


<div id="mimodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Ejemplo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Amigo jolsalazar, es correcto, muchas gracias por responder, ya lo ejecuté y logro hacer click en la imagen para que me abra la ventana modal.Sin embargo sólo me queda un detalle y es que la imagen a la que hago click debe salir en la ventana modal. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Primero que todo me alegra que haya funcionado, ahora bien, si la respuesta te dio la opcion de realizarlo de forma correcta debes puntuar la respuesta. Ya que tu pregunta posterior no es lo mismo por lo que preguntaste.